# Number of equations required for elimination

Tags: determinant, systems-of-equations

I was studying determinants, and the topic that came up was the 'eliminant' of a system of equations. My book says that the eliminant of the system of equations:

$$a_1x + b_1y + c_1z = 0$$

$$a_2x + b_2y + c_2z = 0$$

$$a_3x + b_3y + c_3z = 0$$

is

$$\begin{vmatrix}a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Here, three equations are required to eliminate three variables from the system of equations. However, if we know $z=1$, we get three equations in two variables. But we still need *at least* three equations to be able to eliminate $x, y$.

I don't understand the logic behind this. Precisely how many equations are needed to eliminate all the variables? Is there any intuitive way to understand the process of elimination (not *how* to eliminate but what elimination actually means) and see the reason for this?